# Accessing one function in many classes

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, repeat

I have a facebook graph request  of the following:

```
    let request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
    request.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in })
```

I keep repeating the graph request in every class to access my facebook id. I tried storing it in NSUserDefaults, which worked, though created a lot of bugs and random crashes. I'm wondering whats the best way to reuse this completion block in every class without having to call it over and over.

Comment: Have you heard of DRY? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a lot of calls you should really just make a class that handles your network requests and funnel all of your requests through it. Then everything is centralized and if the API changes, your code will be a lot more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Swift functions are naturally global. It doesn't look like this relies on anything other than the Facebook SDK, so you can just create a new file and stick it in there.

```
//FBSDKGraphRequest.swift (Or any other name you want)

import FBSDKCoreKit // Or whichever you need

func graphRequest() {
    let request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
    request.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in })
}
```

And you can call it from anywhere inside your project just using

`graphRequest()`